# Verifying certain keys are present in rest assured response without iterating over the response n number of times

Tags: java, rest-assured

Say that i have a response:

```
{
"lotto":{
        "lottoId":5,
        "winning-numbers":[2,45,34,23,7,5,3],
        "winners":[{
                 "winnerId":23,
                 "numbers":[2,45,34,23,3,5]
                  },
                  {"winnerId":54,
                   "numbers":[52,3,12,11,18,22]
                  }]
        }
}
```

I want to verify that winnerId and numbers are present in response but i don't want to iterate over the response twice because in my case the response is very big and I may have to validate hundreds of values and that will waste a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to iterate over the json multiple times. Just de-serialise the response to a pojo and then you can perform n number of validation on that by storing in an appropriate data-structure. Please share what problem you are facing exactly.